# Append a class to an editable div when it changes its height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, contenteditable

I have editable div with overflow set to hidden, I'd like the div to expand as the user types (if needed). II'm using jquery to change the class of the div each time the height changes.
I cant seem to get to work at all, it chnages the class but nothing happens

> [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z23f8xak/)

HTML:

```
<div class="contanier">
  <div class="1" id="msgWriteArea" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#msgWriteArea{
    outline: 0;
  border: none;
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
  height:20px;
  line-height:20px;
  font-size:18px;
  border:solid 1px #000;
  background:#FFF;
}
.contanier .1{
  height:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.contanier .2{
  height:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.contanier .3{
  height:60px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.contanier .4{
  height:80px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.contanier .5{
  height:80px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var chatBoxSize = {
    oldHeight : 0,
    scrollHeight : 0,
    lastClass : 1,
    maxClass : 5
};
function updateChatSize() {
    var id = '#msgWriteArea';
    var element = document.querySelector(id);
    if((element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight) || (element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth)){
        if(chatBoxSize.lastClass == null){
            //add size 1
            console.log('ADD SIZE 1');
            $(id).addClass('1');
            chatBoxSize.lastClass = '1';
        } else if(chatBoxSize.oldHeight != $(id)[0].scrollHeight){
            //get the correct size to add
            if(parseInt(current) >= parseInt(chatBoxSize.maxClass)){
                var current = chatBoxSize.maxClass,
                last = parseInt(chatBoxSize.maxClass) - 1;
                chatBoxSize.lastClass = current;
                console.log('IS AT MAX SIZE');
            } else if(chatBoxSize.scrollHeight < $(id)[0].scrollHeight){
                var current = parseInt(chatBoxSize.lastClass) + 1,
                last = parseInt(chatBoxSize.lastClass);
                chatBoxSize.lastClass = current;
            } else if(chatBoxSize.scrollHeight > $(id)[0].scrollHeight) {
                var current = parseInt(chatBoxSize.lastClass) - 1,
                last = parseInt(chatBoxSize.lastClass);
                chatBoxSize.lastClass = current;
            } else {
                //console.log('No Change in height');
            }
      if(last != undefined){
        console.log('Add', current, 'Remove', last);
        $('#msgWriteArea').addClass(current + "");
                $('#msgWriteArea').removeClass(last + "");
        $('#display').val('Add ' + current + ' Remove' + last);
      }
        }
        chatBoxSize.oldHeight = element.offsetHeight;
        chatBoxSize.scrollHeight = $(id)[0].scrollHeight;
        chatBoxSize.oldHeight = element.offsetHeight;
    }
};
$(function (){
    $('#msgWriteArea').bind('change keydown input', function () {
        if(event.type == 'keydown'){
            updateChatSize();
        }
    });
});
```

This is part of a larger page. So would need to the class to change on other elements but just one for now to get the hang of how this works

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/4L3210w9/?

Comment: yeah how did you do that?

Comment: oh nevermind I see how that works, this is part of a larger page. So would need to the class to change on other elements but just working on one as a base

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding this CSS:

```
#msgWriteArea{
    height: auto !important;
    max-height: 80px; // Max Chat Box Size.. 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

See [***JsFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/of7rzwLa/)

Comment: Thanks that works but I still need the class to change as I need to log this on other elements on the page

Answer (score 0):

if you set a fix height to `contenteditable` this won't expand vertically,
so to begin with remove height attribute;

then using `line-height` attribute instead of `el.offsetHeight` (in the evaluation for adding a class depending on height) should fix your fiddle;

### [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/z23f8xak/2/)